# Change Quartz appender in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, quartz-scheduler, log4j2, configuration-files

I'm trying to redirect all Quartz logging to a separate file, but it still keeps logging into the console. What am I doing wrong in the configuration file?

Here's a simplified version of my log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <!--stuff-->
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="Quartz">
            <!--stuff-->
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.quartz" level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="Quartz"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.rotoplastyc" level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="OFF">
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: This looks correct. Quartz uses slf4j for logging—perhaps it's configured separately. You'll need the `log4j-slf4j-impl` bridge on your class path to pass Quartz logging through log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that, as @teppic suggested in the comments, I needed the `log4j-slf4j-impl` lib in order for it to work properly, I was currently using the `slf4j-simple` lib which only logs into the console.